# Find minimum one element that matches the criteria in the array using typescript in angular 7

Tags: angular

I basically need to search for any occurrence of the value `true` in the array using typescript in angular 7.

If you notice below `this.DocumentSelected[i] = true;` if the condition is met. Ideally I would like to have exited here but the return doesn't work
within the map. Hence I am trying to initialise the array and the check if there is one value containing `true` then exit the method.

```js
DocumentSelected: any = [];

this.files.map(doc => {
  if (doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id === null) {
    this.DocumentSelected[i] = true;
    return;
  }

  const datestr = (new Date(doc.selectedDate)).toUTCString();

  formData.append('documentTypeId' + i++, doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id.toString());
  formData.append('documentDate' + j++, datestr);

  const fileEntry = doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;

  fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
    formData.append('file' + k++, file, doc.name);
  });
});

if (this.DocumentSelected) {
  this.notify.error('Please select the Document Type');
  return;
}
```

Comment: There's some wierdness in your code. You're setting `DocumentSelected` as an empty object `{}` but then attempting to target an index of `DocumentSelected[i]` as if it is an array. You need to be more clear with what you're trying to achieve here and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if anyone is going to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that . It is [] and not {}

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will iterate over an array and return another array.

You're not using `map()` the way it was intended to be used as you're not looking to output an array.

For purely iterative purposes you should use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a traditional `for` loop if you need access to an `i` iterator index.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
  const doc = this.files[i];

  if (doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id === null) {
    this.DocumentSelected[i] = true;
    break; // <-- terminate for loop
  }
}
```

Comment: So I use the traditional approach, i could just exit based on the return statement you mean

Comment: Correct, just `return` from the traditional `for` loop as needed.

Comment: What are you expecting to return?

Comment: I just want to terminate. Now what is happening is based on the number of items it is displaying the message. I want the notification error message shown only once

Comment: A traditional for loop is what you're looking for here. You need to use `break` to terminate the for loop early. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Cant the same be done in the forEach loop. But when I used break there I get error message Jump target cannot cross function boundary

Comment: No. There is no built in way to `break` out of the `forEach` method. If you need that functionality then `forEach` is not the right method for you. `forEach` is not supposed to replace a `for` loop - it's there if you need a quicker, less feature rich iterator.

Comment: I have achieved the same in forEach loop with a return statment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196329/discussion-between-andrew-hill-and-tom).